# How to remove a particular character if it appears between two boundaries

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with many lines of text in it. I need to remove all instances of the quote `"` character. However, I only want to remove them if they fall between two boundaries.

e.g. an example line may look like:

`"status":0,"text":"some stuff goes in here. and some more "here","user":"1234"`

The lower boundary would be `"text":"` and the upper boundary would be `","user"`

So in the line above there would be just one `"` removed (before the word 'here').

I've seen loads of examples on how to remove **everything** between two boundaries, but can't find anything more targeted. I'm sure the question has been asked many times (so I apologise), but I can't seem to find the answer, so if someone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: so basically you want  to remove all `"` between start from `"text":"` and end with `","user"`?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` you can do:

```
sed -E ':a s/("text":"[^"]*)"(.*)(","user")/\1\2\3/;ta' infile
```

- first captured group containing `"text":"` followed by any character but a double quote mark `[^"]*`
- a single first seen double quote
- second captured group contains anything after above `(.*)`
- third captured group is `","user"`.
- `:a s/find/replace/; ta` jump to label `a` if substitution was successful; every repeat we removes that single quote found `"` and return back everything else (three captured groups)

Comment: It hasn't worked unfortunately. I just tried it on one of my files, and it still has multiple " in it. `sed -E ':a s/("text":"[^"]*)"(.*)(","user")/\1\2\3/;ta' filename`

Comment: @IGGt Ahh, I thought you know how to use sed's `-i` switch which is for in-place replace. so you will need to apply that to save changes on your file like `sed -Ei ...`

Comment: Sorry, it's been a really long day. . . That is perfect and works like a charm,